# Number of Nonisomorphic Subgroups of Finite Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Lets say I have an abelian group $G$ with order $n$ and I am given the primary components of $G$ and their type. How can I determine how many nonisomorphic subgroups of $G$ there are? And as an extension, how can I enumerate them?
Please explain without using Sylow theorems.

As a concrete example:
Say $|G|=108$ and $G(2)$ and $G(3)$ have types $(2)$ and $(2,1)$ respectively. How many nonisomorphic subgroups does $G$ have?

Comment: What is your definition of primary factors and types?

Comment: I meant primary components (and hence elementary divisors). I will edit the post. By primary components I mean the following:
$|G|=p^{n_1}_1\cdot \cdot \cdot p^{n_m}_m$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes, then $G=G(p_1)\oplus ... \oplus G(p_m)$. Then $G(p_i)$ are the primary components of $G$ and $p^{a_i}_i$ are the elementary divisors.

Comment: To explain what I mean by types, say $G(2)=\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. Then the type of $G(2)$ is $(2,1)$, i.e. the exponents of the modulus of each term of the primary component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found an answer that I hope generalizes. For the concrete example given, the subgroups of $G$ are direct sums of subgroups of each component with the same or lower type.
Up to isomorphism, the subgroups of $G(2)$ are $\{0\}, \{0,2\},$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$.
Up to isomorphism, the subgroups of $G(3)$ are $\mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_9, \mathbb{Z}_9 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3,$ and $\{0\}$. Thus the subgroups of $G$ are all combinations (using the direct sum operator) of each of these so we have $15$ subgroups of $G$ up to isomorphism.